# Why is 1...2 equivalent to "10.2" in PHP?

Tags: php, type-conversion, operators, symbols

Just a second ago I was playing around with PHP, trying to figure out if there was a native range function (eventually finding `range`). However, one of the things I tried was the following:

```php
echo 1...2;
```

which to my surprise returns the string `"10.2"`. Can anyone tell me exactly what syntax is responsible for this? It doesn't seem like a valid place for a splat operator.

Comment: you tried `1...2`, what does that mean? There is a lot missing from this question, if you are referring to some code, you need to include it, not just vaguely allude to it

Comment: @tim you can reproduce it with just `echo 1...2;`

Comment: yeah, well at least that's valid code, thanks @Barmar

Comment: @tim I'm sorry, this question was totally unclear. Projects using Laravel use a PHP REPL (PsySH, rebranded as "tinker"). Sometimes I forget that other PHP developers don't use a REPL too often. So any *expression* gets, in essence, echo'd but it's actually slightly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement consists of three parts: `1.`, `.` and `.2`. The first one evaluates to the number `1`, the second one is the string concatenation operator, and the latter one evaluates to `0.2`. Thus, you get `10.2`.

Equivalent example code:

```php
$a = 1.;
$b = .2;
echo "a = $a\n";
echo "b = $b\n";
echo "a.b = ".($a.$b)."\n";
```

outputs

```
a = 1
b = 0.2
a.b = 10.2
```